# Using one-to-one and one-to-many on the same entity in doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I need to store specified properties state of entity `Product` - `price` and `currency`.

So I have the following schema for `Product`:

```yaml
Product:
   type: entity
   table: product
   fields:
       id:
           type: string
           length: 36
           id: true
           generator:
               strategy: UUID
       price:
           type: float
       currency:
           type: string
           length: 3
       created:
           type: datetime
           gedmo:
               timestampable:
                   on: create
       updated:
           type: datetime
           gedmo:
               timestampable:
                   on: update

   lifecycleCallbacks:
       prePersist: [ prePersist ]
       preUpdate: [ preUpdate ]

   oneToOne:
       lastPriceRevision:
           cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
           targetEntity: PriceRevision
           joinColumn:
               name: last_price_revision_id
               referencedColumnName: id
   oneToMany:
       priceRevisions:
           cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
           targetEntity: PriceRevision
           mappedBy: product
```

And `PriceRevision` entity schema

```yaml
PriceRevision:
    type: entity
    table: price_revision
    fields:
        id:
            type: string
            length: 36
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: UUID
        price:
            type: float
        currency:
            type: string
            length: 3
        created:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: create
        updated:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: update
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

    manyToOne:
        product:
            targetEntity: Product
            inversedBy: priceRevisions
            joinColumn:
                name: product_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

On Product `prePersist` and `preUpdate` I do the following:

```php
    $priceRevision = $this->getLastPriceRevision();

    if (!$priceRevision || $this->getPrice() !== $priceRevision->getPrice()
        || $this->getCurrency() !== $priceRevision->getCurrency() 
    ) {
        $priceRevision = new PriceRevision();
        $priceRevision->setPrice($this->getPrice());
        $priceRevision->setCurrency($this->getCurrency());
        $this->addPriceRevision($priceRevision);
        $this->setLastPriceRevision($priceRevision);
    }
```

On creating `Product` - all works fine and as expected. New product created and it has `PriceRevision` with the same `price` and `currency`.

But when I tried to change `Product`'s `price` I got the error in UnitOfWork.

```
Notice: Undefined index: 000000006c4cf70000000000719f69a2
```

it happens here. Looks like the same entity `PriceRevision` has different spl_object_hash.

```php
public function getEntityIdentifier($entity)
{
    return $this->entityIdentifiers[spl_object_hash($entity)];
}
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

I found several similar questions here, but they are not solved. And some of them refernced to `AuditEntity` bundle.

Comment: I don't understand the last part. You've mentioned about error in `getEntityIdentifier` which was not used in the code before. Also I don't really get the point of using `spl_object_hash` here.

Comment: @dragoste `getEntityIdentifier` is a method used in doctrine. https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L2898

Comment: Ah, ok. But still, we don't know which part of your code (which line actually) causes the issue.

Comment: @dragoste I thought it is clearly. All happens on persist (`EntityManager`'s persist method). But because persists did by  SonataAdmin I didn't not mention about it to do not do the question too complicated..

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to put

```
$priceRevision->setProduct($this);
```

into the `prePersist` and `preUpdate` methods?

Comment: I do this inside method `addPriceRevision()`